# Can NumPy take care that an array is (nonstrictly) increasing along one axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a function in numpy to guarantee or rather fix an array such that it is (nonstrictly) increasing along one particular axis?
For example, I have the following 2D array:

```
X = array([[1, 2, 1, 4, 5],
           [0, 3, 1, 5, 4]])
```

the output of `np.foobar(X)` should return

```
array([[1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
       [0, 3, 3, 5, 5]])
```

Does `foobar` exist or do I need to do that manually by using something like `np.diff` and some smart indexing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) for a running (accumulated) max value along that axis to ensure the strictly increasing criteria -

```
np.maximum.accumulate(X,axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [233]: X
Out[233]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 4, 5],
       [0, 3, 1, 5, 4]])

In [234]: np.maximum.accumulate(X,axis=1)
Out[234]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
       [0, 3, 3, 5, 5]])
```

For memory efficiency, we can assign it back to the input for in-situ changes with its `out` argument.

**Runtime tests**

Case #1 : Array as input

```
In [254]: X = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [255]: %timeit np.maximum.accumulate(X,axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop

# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's pandas soln using df.cummax
In [256]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(X).cummax(axis=1).values
100 loops, best of 3: 4.81 ms per loop
```

Case #2 : Dataframe as input

```
In [257]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,1000))

In [258]: %timeit np.maximum.accumulate(df.values,axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop

# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's pandas soln using df.cummax
In [259]: %timeit df.cummax(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.68 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` offers you the `df.cummax` function:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(X).cummax(axis=1).values

array([[1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
       [0, 3, 3, 5, 5]])
```

It's useful to know that there's a first class function on hand in case your data is already loaded into a dataframe.

Comment: I like pandas and use it a lot, but in this particular case I only have numpy arrays and I don't want to create a new frame on the fly, just for this :-). But still, thanks, good to know that pandas has that, too!

Comment: @SmCaterpillar No problem. It certainly doesn't make sense on it's own. You'd consider this if your data is already _in_ a dataframe. :)